# Jersey 2.17 Multipart Upload issue

Tags: tomcat, jersey

**Request Payload:**

```
------WebKitFormBoundary0xo2c20i17MGYe0B
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="autoTest.wav"
Content-Type: audio/wav


------WebKitFormBoundary0xo2c20i17MGYe0B--
```

**Jersey Upload Code Snippet:**

```
@POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadGreetings(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail)
```

Also implemented the following dependency injection code using ResourceConfig,

```
register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

With the above mentioned facts, I am trying to upload the file as seen with above request payload. But when i submit, i am getting the following exception in the tomcat log,

**Exception Log**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A descriptor SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.ServerProcessingBinder$CloseableServiceFactory
    contracts={org.glassfish.jersey.server.CloseableService}
    scope=org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=PROVIDE_METHOD
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder$2@3c5e76f7
    proxiable=true
    proxyForSameScope=false
    analysisName=null
    id=18
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=1574203671
    reified=true) requires a proxy, but the proxyable library is not on the classpath
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2034)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:711)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:661)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.IterableProviderImpl.get(IterableProviderImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderServerSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderServerSide.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:853)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:785)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider$ValueFactory.getEntity(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider$FormDataParamValueFactory.provide(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:158)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:401)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
```

Note: I am using Jersey 2.17 version along with 1.93 version of the `mimepull.jar`.

Please help to identify what causes this problem.

Comment: Are you adding all the Jars yourself, or are you using Maven? The error is saying something about a missing library. If the former, download the [RI Bundle from here](https://jersey.java.net/download.html) and make sure to add _all_ the jars, and of course the extra multipart and mimpull jars that don't come in the bundle

Comment: @peeskillet : adding it manually. Let me check on your suggestion and get back to you

Comment: Also I would update the [multipart jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart/2.22.2) too, since the Jersey version I linked to is the latest 2.22.1 version. I don't think the mimepull version has changed, so I don't think you'll need to update that

Comment: @peeskillet : I have used both the version of 2.22.1 & 2.17 and it gives me the same exception. Not sure what i am missing here. Also tried to use the  1.96 version of mime but ended up with the same exception

Comment: This solution (adding current javassist to classpath) helped in my case.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309690/exception-while-using-jersey-declarative-linking

Comment: @genobis you should answer the question so it's more obvious to people what your solution is. You saved my day and I almost skipped the question without reading the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was running tomcat on my local and adding javassist to classpath helped me to resolve this issue as mentioned by @genobis